# Creating models and template names based on variables

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to start by saying that I know this is possibly both unconventional and bad practice, but here goes.

I've got a UserProfile model. In the form for this model, a user gets to select what template they want to use on their blog. In doing this, they'll select either 1, 2, or 3 from a drop down menu. This number will be saved to field 'template' within the UserProfile model.

Upon hitting the submit button, I'd like the following to happen:

1) I'd like for a TemplateProfilex to be created where x is equal to the template number they selected.

To give you an idea of what I'd like to happen (even though I know that this won't work), here is the code.

```
x = user.userprofile.template

Model = TemplateProfile + 'x'

blog = Model.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

**The goal here would be to create TemplateProfile3 for this user if the user selected 3 on the form.**

2) Next, once the model is created and the user is redirected to the next view, I'd like to send this user to a template as determined by the value in user.userprofile.template

```
return render(request, 'accounts/templateX.html', args) where X is the value in user.userprofile.template
```

If I could do something as described above, it would dramatically simplify my code. The alternative is to do a bunch of if statements in my views. Example:

```
if user.userprofile.template == 1: 

   template_profile= TemplateProfile1.objects.create(user=request.user)

   return render(request, 'accounts/template1.html', args)
```

Thanks a ton guys.

Comment: It seems you're trying to solve a problem at the wrong level, but I don't understand what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure. In your example, you could get rid of the `if` statements by doing `'accounts/template{}.html'.format(user.userprofile.template)`.

Comment: awesome, thank you!